# ASP.Net MVC and state - How to update the database from Session changes in dual listboxes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a dual listbox system where the operator can assign and remove different exercises to a specific users regime.  For the `RemoveExercises` function, i have started using a Session so that the `RequestedExercises` listbox is updated with the changes made (the adding and removing of exercises).

Currently the `AddExercises` function adds the exercise from the `AvailableExercises` listbox to the `RequestedExercises` listbox (also known as `RegimeItems`) on the database but it doesn't show up on the `RequestedExercises` listbox until i go back into the page.

The `RemoveExercises` function however, removes a selected exercise from the `RequestedExercises` listbox but doesn't make the changes to the database. So both functions only do half of what i want them to do but in different ways.

This has led me to believe that added exercise is not showing up on the `RequestedExercises` listbox because of the session state, and the `RemoveExercises` is not updating its changes to the database. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**: after changing `return View(model);` to `return RedirectToAction("ExerciseIndex", new { id = model2.UserID, vmodel = model2 });` in the post request, add exercises works perfectly. **How should i make it so that RemoveExercises works on the domain object User?**

**Controller.cs**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ExerciseIndex(int id, UserExerciseViewModel vmodel)
    {
        User user = db.Users.Find(id);
        UserExerciseViewModel model = new UserExerciseViewModel { AvailableExercises = GetAllExercises(), RequestedExercises = ChosenExercises(user, vmodel) };
        model.UserID = user.UserID;
        Session["UserExerciseViewModel"] = model;
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ExerciseIndex(UserExerciseViewModel model, string add, string remove, string send, int id, RegimeItem item)
    {
        UserExerciseViewModel model2 = (UserExerciseViewModel)(Session["UserExerciseViewModel"]);
        model.RequestedExercises = model2.RequestedExercises;
        model.AvailableExercises = model2.AvailableExercises;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(add))
            AddExercises(model, id);
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(remove))
            RemoveExercises(model, id);
        User user = db.Users.Find(model2.UserID);
        model2.RequestedExercises = ChosenExercises(user, model);
        user.RegimeItems = model.RequestedExercises;
        RestoreSavedState(model, user);
        return RedirectToAction("ExerciseIndex", new { id = model2.UserID, vmodel = model2 });
    )

    void RemoveExercises(UserExerciseViewModel model, int id)
    {
        var userExerciseViewModel = (UserExerciseViewModel)(Session["UserExerciseViewModel"]);
        foreach (int selected in model.RequestedSelected)
        {
            RegimeItem item = model.RequestedExercises.FirstOrDefault(i => i.RegimeItemID == selected);
            if (item != null)
            {
                model.RequestedExercises.Remove(item);
            }
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    void AddExercises(UserExerciseViewModel model, int id)
    {
        var userExerciseViewModel = (UserExerciseViewModel)(Session["UserExerciseViewModel"]);
        foreach (int selected in model.AvailableSelected)
        {
            if (model.AvailableSelected != null)
            {
                User user = db.Users.Find(id);
                user.RegimeItems.Add(new RegimeItem()
                {
                    RegimeExercise = (this.GetAllExercises().FirstOrDefault(i => i.ExerciseID == selected))
                });
            }
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    void RestoreSavedState(UserExerciseViewModel model, User user)
    {
        user.RegimeItems = this.ChosenExercises(user, model);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.SavedRequested))
        {
            string[] exIds = model.SavedRequested.Split(',');
            var regimeItems = ChosenExercises(user, model).Where(p => exIds.Contains(p.RegimeItemID.ToString()));
            model.RequestedExercises.AddRange(regimeItems);
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    private List<Exercise> GetAllExercises() //Gets all the data for AvailableExercises
    {
        return db.Exercises.ToList();
    }

    private List<RegimeItem> ChosenExercises(User user, UserExerciseViewModel model) //Gets all the data for RequestedExercies
    {
     return db.Users
     .Where(u => u.UserID == user.UserID)
     .SelectMany(u => u.RegimeItems)
     .ToList();
    }
```

**Models(cs)**

```
 public class User
    {
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public ICollection<RegimeItem> RegimeItems { get; set; }
        public User()
        {
            this.RegimeItems = new List<RegimeItem>();
        } 
    }
    public class RegimeItem
    {
        public int RegimeItemID { get; set; }
        public Exercise RegimeExercise { get; set; }
    }
```

**ViewModel(cs)**

```
public class UserExerciseViewModel
{
    public List<Exercise> AvailableExercises { get; set; }
    public List<RegimeItem> RequestedExercises { get; set; }
    public int? SelectedExercise { get; set; }
    public int[] AvailableSelected { get; set; }
    public int[] RequestedSelected { get; set; }
    public string SavedRequested { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
}
```

**View(Segment Only(cshtml))**

```
<td valign="top">
   @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.AvailableSelected, new MultiSelectList(Model.AvailableExercises, "ExerciseID", "Name", Model.AvailableSelected))
</td>
<td valign="top">
  <input type="submit" name="add"
  id="add" value=">>" /><br />
  <input type="submit" name="remove"
  id="remove" value="<<" />
</td>
<td valign="top">
    @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.RequestedSelected, new MultiSelectList(Model.RequestedExercises, "RegimeItemID", "RegimeExercise.Name", Model.RequestedSelected))
</td>
```

**Update: Changing RemoveExercises to this fixes the remove problem:**

```
void RemoveExercises(UserExerciseViewModel model, int id)
{
    var userExerciseViewModel = (UserExerciseViewModel)(Session["UserExerciseViewModel"]);
    foreach (int selected in model.RequestedSelected)
    {
        if (model.RequestedSelected != null)
        {
            User user = db.Users.Find(id);
            RegimeItem item = db.RegimeItems.Find(selected);
            item.RegimeExercise = this.GetAllExercises().FirstOrDefault(i => i.ExerciseID == selected); //--this removes the regimeexercise
            user.RegimeItems.Remove(item); //deletes the user's regimeitem
            db.RegimeItems.Remove(item); //removes the regimeitem itself 
        }
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Currently the AddExercises function adds the exercise from the
>   AvailableExercises listbox to the RequestedExercises listbox (also
>   known as RegimeItems) on the database but it doesn't show up on the
>   RequestedExercises listbox until i go back into the page.

It won't because you don't update your model, only the user / database.

```
void AddExercises(UserExerciseViewModel model, int id)
    {
        var userExerciseViewModel = (UserExerciseViewModel)(Session["UserExerciseViewModel"]);
        foreach (int selected in model.AvailableSelected)
        {
            if (model.AvailableSelected != null)
            {
                User user = db.Users.Find(id);
                user.RegimeItems.Add(new RegimeItem()
                {
                    RegimeExercise = (this.GetAllExercises().FirstOrDefault(i => i.ExerciseID == selected))
                });
            }
        }
        db.SaveChanges(); // db is updated but your model isn't
    }
```

> The RemoveExercises function however, removes a selected exercise from
>   the RequestedExercises listbox but doesn't make the changes to the
>   database.

It won't because you only update the model and not the user.

```
 void RemoveExercises(UserExerciseViewModel model, int id)
    {
        var userExerciseViewModel = (UserExerciseViewModel)(Session["UserExerciseViewModel"]);
        foreach (int selected in model.RequestedSelected)
        {
            RegimeItem item = model.RequestedExercises.FirstOrDefault(i => i.RegimeItemID == selected);
            if (item != null)
            {
                model.RequestedExercises.Remove(item);
            }
        }
        db.SaveChanges(); // What is the point of this? You didn't alter the user?
    }
```

Typically what you would do here is make both methods `Add` and `Remove`, work on the domain object `User` so that the database is updated appropriately and then rather than

```
return View(model)
```

you would redirect to your `GET` action.

```
   return RedirectToAction("ExerciseIndex", new { id = model2.ID, vmodel= model2 });
```

You'd normally only return the model to the view if it has errors which you don't even seem to be checking for:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid){ ...}
```

Also watch for how you find a user. You do it once (unconditionally) in `ExerciseIndex` and then again in `Remove`. Why not just do it at the top of `ExerciseIndex` and pass to `Remove`?

Comment: Thanks for this, so by using `return RedirectToAction...`   `AddExercises` works perfectly.  How should i make it so that RemoveExercises works on the domain object `User`?

Comment: Pass your user in and `user.RegimeItems.Remove`.